# Divide sentences by their type(Interrogative/Affirmative)

Tags: python

I have a program that divides the text into sentences, then sentences to words, then сount number of parts of speech and write data to the csv file. The question is this: I need to divide sentences by the category. On an input I want to receive an array of sentences. Then each sentence by punctuation mark at the end of sentence, determine its type. If this is an affirmative sentence, then the flag in csv will be zero, if this is a 
interrogative sentence, then the flag will be 1. How I can do it?

This is code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import pymorphy2
import csv
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
import re

# with open('kuprin.txt', 'r') as myfile:
#     text = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
text="Hi!How are you?My name is Jack.What is your name?"
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer();
s = set(sentences)

for sentences in s:
    # print('-'+sentences)
    words = word_tokenize(sentences)
    print(words)

json_data = []
i = 0
for item in s:
    if item == '':
        continue
    word_list = item.split(' ')
    data = {
        "id": i,
        "sentences": item,
        "ADJF": 0,
        "NOUN": 0,
        "INTJ": 0,
        "ADJS": 0,
        "COMP": 0,
        "VERB": 0,
        "INFN": 0,
        "PRTF": 0,
        "PRTS": 0,
        "GRND": 0,
        "NUMR": 0,
        "ADVB": 0,
        "NPRO": 0,
        "PRED": 0,
        "PREP": 0,
        "CONJ": 0,
        "PRCL": 0,
        "FLAG": 0
    }

    for word in word_list:
        res = morph.parse(word)
        pos = res[0].tag.POS
        if pos == None:
            continue
        print(word + "---" + str(pos))
        data[pos] += 1
    json_data.append(data)
    i = i+1

for el in json_data:
    print(el)

with open('test.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(json_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=False, indent=4, 
separators=(',', ': '))

txt_file = r"test.json"
csv_file = r"test.csv"

in_txt = csv.reader(open(txt_file, "rt"))
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))

out_csv.writerow(
    ["id", "sentences", "ADJF", "NOUN", "INTJ", "ADJS", "COMP", "VERB", 
  "INFN", "PRTF", "PRTS", "GRND", "NUMR",
     "ADVB", "NPRO", "PRED", "PREP", "CONJ", "PRCL"])

for el in json_data:
    csv_str =[]
    for value in el.values():
        csv_str += [value]
    print(csv_str)
    out_csv.writerow(csv_str)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you define `data`, you can add a simple check for the last character in the last word of `word_list`, and edit `data["FLAG"]` accordingly:

```
...
        "PRCL": 0,
        "FLAG": 0
    }

    if word_list[-1][-1] == "?": 
        data["FLAG"] = 1
    else:
        pass

    for word in word_list:
        res = morph.parse(word)
...
```

There are probably more robust ways to do this, but this seems simple enough to do what you need.